# Как убрать маркер у первого элемента в списке?

Tags: html, css

Добавил класс `header__menu_list__first_li` , где  `list-style` выставлен `none`.  Но не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  margin: 92px 50px;
}

.header__menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: center;
}


.header__menu_list {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 32px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  list-style-type: circle;
}

.header__menu_list__first_li {
  list-style-type: none !important;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav class="header__menu">
    <ul class="header__menu_list ">
      <li class="header__menu_list__first_li"><a class="menu-link_active" href="#">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Посмотреть лоты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Об аукционе</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавьте класс `header__menu_list__first_li` в `<li>`, а не `<a>`.

```css
.header__menu_list {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 32px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  list-style-type: circle;
}

.header__menu_list__first_li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header__menu_list ">
  <li class="header__menu_list__first_li">
    <a class="menu-link_active" href="#">Главная</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Посмотреть лоты</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Об аукционе</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

Есть и другой способ. Можно задать `display: block;` первому элементу списка:

```css
.header__menu_list {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 32px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  list-style-type: circle;
}

.header__menu_list__first_li {
  display: block; /* уберет маркер */
}
```

```html
<ul class="header__menu_list ">
  <li class="header__menu_list__first_li"><a class="menu-link_active" href="#">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Посмотреть лоты</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Об аукционе</a></li>
</ul>
```

Эффект будет тот же :)

Comment: дополню первый вариант без доп классов .header__menu_list li:first-child { list-style-type: none; }